# Image style generating hook

Tags: 7, media

I'm using Drupal 7. Is there a hook for generating image from image style? 
For example. I upload an image. When image is displayed for the first time, drupal generates image style. Can I hook to that event somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image style hooks are documented here:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.api.php/7

- hook_image_default_styles:     Provide module-based image styles for reuse throughout Drupal.
- hook_image_effect_info:    Define information about image effects provided by a module.
- hook_image_effect_info_alter:  Alter the information provided in
- hook_image_effect_info.
- hook_image_styles_alter:   Modify any image styles provided by other modules or the user.
- hook_image_style_delete:   Respond to image style deletion.
- hook_image_style_flush:    Respond to image style flushing.
- hook_image_style_save:     Respond to image style updating.

Nothing for the actual image generation process, if that's what you're looking for.

See [image_style_deliver](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_deliver/7) for the details on the image generation

Comment: Thanks for the image_style_deliver() function:) hook_file_load can be injected there:)

Comment: Ah yes, glad it's sorted!

Answer (score 1):

You can define any number of custom image styles (presets). You can then call an image to be embedded using a specific image_style with [theme_image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7)

Answer (score 0):

Hooking your own code into the image derivative generation, image link generation and menu routing is very difficult. In the imagecache_actions contrib module we have had a lot of questions about it. I think that [comments 12](https://www.drupal.org/node/1063430#comment-7207708), 13 and 14 of [issue "Change file format :: Doesn't change the file extension"](https://www.drupal.org/node/1063430) best answer what can be done and what trouble you will probably run into.