# Image style hook?

Tags: 8, media

I am looking for the same answer to this question [Image style generating hook](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/62270/image-style-generating-hook) but in Drupal 8.

I will like to have a hook on image styles, where when an image is an upload and generate styles for it I can get some information about it.

My end goal is to have some meta information about the image, so I can find the location of the image.

Comment: Image styles are config entities, images are in file entities. So the whole system has changed. First look at entity operations, directly or the CRUD hooks. If you can't find what you are looking for, please make the question more specific.